# CSS and Javascript work on internal server but not external

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer

I am working on a website for a friend. He wants a flash animated style website without any flash so that it works on IOS and he can change things himself. I am using JQuery along with my own javascript, and several css files. Now the problem is the website works perfectly on my internal development server on all browsers. When I uploaded it to my sub domain to show him the progress it no longer works on IE. All other browsers work perfect just not IE and only when its on the internet. I've already gone through the w3 validations with no errors. All java and everything is enabled on IE, I'm stumped. Does this happen to anyone else's IE or is it just on my computer?

[Incomplete Demo](http://s421215073.onlinehome.us/13thlegion/)

Comment: Make sure that your various resources are being served with the proper Content-Type headers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS renders differently on web server than on development environment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867383/css-renders-differently-on-web-server-than-on-development-environment)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've got JavaScript errors.

```
 $('div#top').animate ({bottom: '250px', }, timeDuration);
```

That stray comma makes IE unhappy <strike>(even IE9)</strike>.

Of course that would have caused IE to have problems if you served the page from your local server too.

(Oh wait; my IE is stuck in compatibility mode ... well anyway those stray commas will definitely freak out some versions of IE.)