# Internet Explorer 9 compatibility mode

Tags: html, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have this HTML, valid for w3c:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
        <title>COMUNE DI MILANO</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Ciao Mamma</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

I don't know why IE Switch to compatibility mode. 
I found a meta tag that force the compatibility mode, but I want to know how to build a working HTML page..

Someone knows what will cause the switch? It could depends on Apache version / configuration?

Thank's a lot, Davide.

Comment: ISO-8859-1? In 2013? :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS renders differently on web server than on development environment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867383/css-renders-differently-on-web-server-than-on-development-environment)

Comment: You'll right Quentin, it's a test, I usually use UTF-8. 
I set charset to ISO-8859-1 because I'm trying to discover the reason and ISO match with the apache default on a test machine here in office.

Comment: Thanks Quentin for the link, unfortunately I explored the http headers on IE 9, but I didn't see anything strange...

Answer (score 0):

Try check the headers that are sent along with it, see if there's a `X-UA-Compatible` header that's set to something undesirable.

Comment: Unfortunately there are no header set on apache, using this key and this does not result on http headers on the response... mumble mumble...

Comment: You might want to check this question out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726357/why-does-ie9-switch-to-compatibility-mode-on-my-website