# CSS renders differently on local sever as opposed to through internet in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

The CSS looks fine when viewed through the internet. However, in IE8, IE10, and IE11 certain css properties do not load. In the page inspector they show up but are underlined with a red squiggle. I have read the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867383/css-renders-differently-on-web-server-than-on-development-environment) and tried adding `http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"` to my `<meta>` tag since it actually renders properly in IE9 but it didn't help.

Again, loaded locally on any other browser works fine. I would actually be content with that, but I need to run in IE11 on an RT tablet (can't get another browser).

To sum up, most of the CSS does actually load. It seems to only be `background` with a `rgba` on it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using PHP, I've found the most reliable technique is to include this line at the very top of your header -- even before `<!DOCTYPE html>`

```
<?php header('X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge'); ?>
```

That should take care of IE > 9 as well. You can then omit any additional `X-UA-Compatible` tags in your `<head>`.