# Jquery control not working after publishing in web server

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iis-7

I have an asp.net web application which uses a jquery multiple select dropdown list. It works perfectly in VS 2012 development server. But once I publish it to our web server and when I access the page using IP, the control fails and throws script errors. I dont know where to check.

Comment: Are the scripts being served to the client? Open a debugger and make sure they return 200 or 304.

Comment: Have you deployed your scripts too!

Comment: Are there any errors on the browser's developer tool?

Comment: Yes it is throwing script error on the controls javascript. Error is the object is not available. It is like the script file is not accessible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was actually related to rendering of CSS. I found this link from

[CSS renders differently on web server than on development environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867383/css-renders-differently-on-web-server-than-on-development-environment).

Added a meta tag for IE -