# Internet Explorer 11 renders .aspx page differently between localhost and remote server

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, iis

I have an asp.net project that looks exactly like I want it to when I run it in IE 11 via localhost, but when I move it to a remote server the styling breaks down. 
Examples: Bootstrap doesn't load correctly -- I'm using some of the col-md classes to style table column widths. They load fine locally, but not remotely. Also, CSS 3 styling rules aren't handled. Things like transparent backgrounds and border-radius settings are ignored. Again, these CSS rules run fine in IE 11 via localhost.

I've checked everything I know to check: Same web browser (obviously), same version of IIS on my local machine as on the server (IIS 7.5.7600.16385). My application pool settings locally versus remotely are almost the same -- the only difference is that on the server, the "Load User Profile" setting is set to "False". On my local machine it's set to true.

The only difference that I can see is OS: my local box is running Win 7, while the server runs Win Server 2008 R2. I have made sure that all my project files are getting copied to the server correctly.

Firefox and Chrome aren't experiencing this issue. Is there something else I can check to figure out why this is going on?

Comment: Good day. I have been having the similar issue, please refer to my threads: [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39711761/why-rdlc-report-renders-differently-in-different-environments/39729635#39729635), [and two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39732671/what-causes-an-override-of-http-equiv-x-ua-compatible-content-ie-edge-chrome). Over the year, did you manage to find a solution to your problem? Please let me know if it is so, since I have exhausted all options at that point and quite desperate =P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there’s no X-UA-Compatible value and site is in Local Intranet security zone, it will be rendered in EmulateIE  mode by default.

Check this Post about similar issue : [CSS renders differently on web server than on development environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867383/css-renders-differently-on-web-server-than-on-development-environment?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following meta tag helped me resolve this issue on IE 11

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Look at [this page](https://www.lifewire.com/xua-compatible-meta-tag-3469059) for further clarifications