# ASP.Net Page rendering CSS Enabled Pages Differently When Deployed

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I've been working a web app in ASP.NET. I have tested on the local computer (localhost) and the web pages are rendered as I want them. But each time i deploy the entire project to the server, text, forms could get displaced, arrangement of divs is entirely different. I'm trying to go through my CSS and testing as well, but can't seem to find what the problem is.

Please, is there anyone that has experienced similar situation and what was the solution?

Comment: take a look at the accepted answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867383/css-renders-differently-on-web-server-than-on-development-environment, also, maybe the old style is in cache, press Ctrl + F5 to make a full request (including the modified css)

Comment: Have you opened the browsers' dev console, and looked at the network traffic and requests to make sure all your resources, such as CSS and javascript, are indeed loading correctly? An incorrect path to css or js could lead to it loading in localhost but not on another environment.

Comment: which browser are you using to test it? It could be a bug in IE8 rendering pages differently in localhost and on the web

Comment: @Sim1 I use IE and Chrome to test it. But when it was deployed to the server, I used Firefox to view the webpages.