# IE9 Web Page Being Rendered Differently After Moving onto Production Server

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, iis

I've just moved my web application onto the production server, which I access via a 192.168.***.*** scheme, after being on a development server which was accessed with a hostname. My page is now being rendered differently even after using a `X-US-Compatible: IE=Edge` HTTP header as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867383/css-renders-differently-on-web-server-than-on-development-environment).

Here are the response headers from the development server:

```
Response    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma  no-cache
Content-Type    text/html
Expires Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Server  Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.4.24
X-Powered-By    ASP.NET
Date    Fri, 28 Aug 2015 15:04:50 GMT
Content-Length  68973
```

And the response headers from the production server:

```
Response    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma  no-cache
Content-Type    text/html; charset=UTF-8
Expires Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Server  Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.6.0
X-Powered-By    ASP.NET
X-UA-Compatible IE=Edge
Date    Fri, 28 Aug 2015 15:04:40 GMT
Content-Length  68973
```

The fonts and text inputs on the page are being rendered bigger, and the buttons are being rendered smaller. The developer console says that both pages are being rendered in IE9 standards mode.

Any help is very much appreciated thank you.

Comment: Can you check the browser mode ? Is it same for both ?

Comment: Yes both are in IE9. The content of the page is inside a frame being served from the same domain, if that's a factor.

Comment: No that should not be a factor, can you check document mode (Should be IE9 Standard) along with browser mode.

Comment: Like I mentioned in my question, the developer console also says that they're both being rendered in IE9 standards mode.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot for both of your pages ? Then it will be easier to look into...