# CSS different from development environment to web server

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer-8

I just put a web page up on a server yesterday, and some things are different than they were in the development environment. There are a few things with different colors, but I'm mostly concerned with how the jQuery autocomplete search widget is appearing. It no longer looks like a drop down list like it did before. It appears in bullet point format with a transparent background.
I remember fixing this when I first installed the widget in development stages. I found another post regarding similar issues [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867383/css-renders-differently-on-web-server-than-on-development-environment) but everything is referring to IE8. My issues are occurring in Chrome.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Are all the paths still correct on your production environment? open the dev tools (F12) and check the net panel to see if there are resources that aren't loading.

Comment: @TimothyGroote all I have is a warning regarding fabric.js. The CSS file that styles the widget is present, but appears blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there was no issue with the browsers, or with any of the files. The issue was that my server was not returning the correct MIME type. One line of code in a config file later, a server restart, and the issue is solved. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you didn't push every file, maybe you missed a .css or .js file? Or the path to such files is different on the server? Open the console in chrome **(CTRL+SHIFT+I)** and look for a 404 error or missing files.

Comment: looks like you might be on to something. I went to inspect element -> sources and selected the CSS file that styles the widget. While the file is present, it appears to be blank. Not sure why though.

Comment: maybe just upload that file again and make sure it's the latest version, if you're using anything like grunt or ruby to minify make sure you're not getting any errors there

Comment: No luck. I go to the file directory where the CSS file is being pulled from and checked and it is populated and the latest version. Just seems like Chrome won't have it.

Comment: No change after that either

Comment: When I run it on Firefox from the machine on which it is hosted, it works just fine

Comment: something is cached pretty hard. If the developer console is open in chrome you can right click the reload button and opt to **Empty Cache and Hard Reload**

Comment: No change. I tried to open the CSS file directly in the browser by typing in the file path. It automatically downloaded it, and it is populated when I open it. That sound right?

Comment: does the path to your files include something like www.yourdomain.local/css instead of www.yourdomain.com/css which would obviously work when your on the machine it's hosted by

Comment: when you say typing the file path downloaded the file, is that from the hosting machine?

Comment: I'm on the company network, so I access the file by referencing the name of the server (lets call it myServer) from where I'm getting the files followed by the file path. When I use firefox on a remote session with myServer, everything works fine. When I use any browser on my own machine (still on company network), I encounter the problem

Comment: Turned out to me an issue with the server returning the wrong MIME type. Thank you, though!

Answer (score 1):

Try checking browser's console for any errors or 404s. Also, turn off the adblocker or other such plugins as they may block some files being loaded because of their file names.

Comment: does Chrome have any of those as defaults?

Comment: F12 invokes developers tools, there is Console tab at the top. To check for any extensions, go to Settings->Extensions.